# How do I let VScode use the newest Ruby Parser for RuboCop

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubygems, lint, rubocop

The problem looks like this:
[image: lint]

I am using a MacBook Air (M2). The Ruby version is ruby 3.1.2p20, and the parser version is 3.3.7. These are the related extensions I have, all the settings are default. I looked all over the web and couldn't find a solution. I want VSCode to use the newest Ruby parser so it won't throw an error when I try to use pattern matching in Ruby, which is introduced in Ruby 2.7.
[image: extensions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `ruby-rubocop` VS code extension

and

in project folder

in  `.rubocop.yml`
add/update line

`AllCops:`

`TargetRubyVersion: 3.3.7`